# metaseo and pagetitle for tx_news

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I use TYPO3 7.6 with tx_news and metaseo, all works fine, except the PageTitle for the news.

I have my news PageTitle and with metaseo I get a second pageTitle "News Single view".
How can I remove the metaseo title? 
Or how can I get the right news title with metaseo?

The following gives the right news title:

```
config.noPageTitle = 2

[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    temp.newsTitle = RECORDS
    temp.newsTitle {
        source = {GP:tx_news_pi1|news}
        source.insertData = 1
        tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
        conf {
            tx_news_domain_model_news >
            tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
            tx_news_domain_model_news {
                field = title
                noTrimWrap = || News|
            }
        }
    }
[global]
page.headerData {
    190 >
    190 = COA
    190 < temp.newsTitle
    #190.wrap = <title>|</title>
    190.wrap = <title>| Вера бахаи в Беларуси</title>
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    page.headerData {
        190 >
        190 = COA
        190 < temp.newsTitle
        #190.wrap = <title>|</title>
        190.wrap = <title>| Суполкi бахаi ў Беларусi</title>
    }
[global]
```

Comment: You don't need line `190 = COA`. You overwrite them one step later with `190 < temp.newsTitle` and __temp.newsTitle__ is a content object type RECORDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EXT:metaseo I found in setup.txt the following line:

```
config.titleTagFunction = Metaseo\Metaseo\Page\Part\PagetitlePart->main
```

Try to extend your TypoScript and delete config.titleTagFunction

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    config.noPageTitle = 2
    config.titleTagFunction >
[global]
```

@see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#nopagetitle and 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#titletagfunction

It's always good to use the TypoScript Object Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution,

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 27]

    config.noPageTitle = 2

    temp.newsTitle = RECORDS
    temp.newsTitle {
        dontCheckPid = 1
        tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
        source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        source.intval = 1
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
            field = title
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        wrap = <title>|</title>
    }
    page.headerData.1 >
    page.headerData.1 < temp.newsTitle

[global]
```

Here, use your news detail page id instead of 27. this will override default page title with current detail news title.

**Resource:** https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html